# How to set datetime timezone in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an SP with a bunch of queries that use datetime like `Getdate()`.

Is there a way that I can set a global flag at the beginning of the SP to set a timezone offset for the datetimes?

I need something like the `set dateformat dmy`, but to offset the timezone.

Comment: As soon as timezones enter the picture, it's almost always more sensible to just work with UTC in the database. Is that not an option for you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sure the time is in UTC, but I need to offset it for reporting purposes

Comment: What are you expecting from this global flag? What effect should it have on your data? Can you provide one or two code fragments detailing your requirements?

Comment: If you're alright with the TZ-offset of the server and not dealing with past / future dates, you may have a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194439/utc-datetime-offset) - There is a regread-function to get tz-info. But it refers to SQL-server-setting.

Comment: I recently solved a bunch of T-sql timezone issues with https://tsqltoolbox.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magical global offset variable that will change the time reported by SQL Server for a a session.  If you think about it, you'll notice that variables declared in a procedure *never* affect the server.  You'd need something in, say, the SET command to do that.

I assume the application provides the offset, based on the TZ database or equivalent, and you just want to apply it as easily as possible.  What you could do is wrap `getdate()` with a new function `localedate()` that accepts as input the offset and applies it to `getdate()` with `dateadd()`.

Bear in mind that dates saved in the database have no associated time zone. Localizing them would be a bigger undertaking.