# Converting AX 2012 UTC dates

Tags: t-sql, datetime, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Trying to extract datetime data from AX 2012 R2 I am hitting a problem. The datetime information is stored in two fields "DATETIME" and "DATETIMETZID" - the former holds the UTC datetime value and the latter the TZID that the former was input with. I need to convert the datetime information into the datetime of the timezone where it was input.

Currently in the GMT+1 Copenhagen time zone, my data input is listed as TZID=37001 - but I dont know where to get a translation of the TZID to a +/- offset value. E.g. if I input a datetime now I would get "2016-01-19 14:32" in the datetime field since that is the UTC datetime and a 37001 in the *TZID field.

Comment: FYI: The field also contains Daylight Savings Time rules

Comment: Take a look at table [TimeZonesRulesData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/timezonesrulesdata.aspx), I think column `RuleId` in that table corresponds with the `TZID`. Also related [Axapta/DynamicsAx: UTC datetime conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205612/axapta-dynamicsax-utc-datetime-conversion)

Comment: I know this post is old, but did you find any solution, how to use the TZID to convert the date time?

Comment: @Englund0110 - I did not get a solution to the original problem. However, I created a couple of functions that would convert to and from UTC based on the DATAAREAID. It's far from an ideal solution since it trashes any change of queries going parallel - but it works until I can find a better solution - which is a big plus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My problem is not really a tsql problem, but i have to convert the dates to the correct timezone. But i just found the the TIMEZONERULESDATA and TIMEZONELIST in the AX database. So by mixing those two tables, and getting the TIMEZONEKEYNAME, i can use TimeZoneInfo in .NET to convert to the correct date. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, depending on your scenario, you can use **SWITCHOFFSET**  /**TODATETIMEOFFSET** in T-SQL:

See this links:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/15/sql-server-datetime-function-switchoffset-example/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/16/sql-server-datetime-function-todatetimeoffset-example/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, depending on your scenario, you can use this DateTimeUtil Methods:

**DateTimeUtil::getTimeZoneOffset** 
.

**DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset**
.

**DateTimeUtil::removeTimeZoneOffset**
.

**DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone()**

Do a job trying to manipulate your date scenario using DateTimeUtil. Anything, try to expose more examples your problem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/datetimeutil.applytimezoneoffset.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc554388(v=ax.50).aspx

Comment: I think OP is looking for an SQL expression to solve the problem and not for a solution using x++.

Comment: @Rodolfo, Thank you for the reply - I'm sure it Works great in x++, but I am querying the database directly through ODBC and won't have access to any methods or conversion that relies on x++ code.